# Passing data to Modal box from variable data-index

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to pass data to Bootstrap Modal Box via data-index. My html markup and javascript snippet is given below. I've not idea how can I fill image, hyperlink and title from variable.

```
function showModal(a) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-index");
    $("#modal-photo").html('<img src=""/>');
    $("#modal-title").html('<a href="">description goes here</a>');
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
}


<div class='post' data-index='1'>
<img src="">
<a class="desc" href="">description goes here</a>
</div>

<div class='post' data-index='2'>
<img src="">
<a class="desc" href="">description goes here</a>
</div>

<div class='post' data-index='3'>
<img src="">
<a class="desc" href="">description goes here</a>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I'm thinking to wrap description into paragraph tag for following code. I don't know if its efficient method or not.

```
function showModal(a) {
    var photo = $("img", $(this).parent()).attr("data-index");
    var title = $("p", $(this).parent()).attr("data-index");
    $("#modal-photo").html('<img src="'+photo+'"/>');
    $("#modal-title").html('<a href="">'+title+'</a>');
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
}
```

But still hyperlink is unavailable to me :D

Comment: What is triggering `showModal()`?

Comment: $('.open-it').on('click', function () { showModal($(this).attr('data-index')) })

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.open-it').on('click', showModal);

function showModal(e) {

    var index = $(this).parent().data('index');
    console.log(index);
    //do stuff
}
```

`this` will not refer to the link in your example. It will point to the `window` object.

The code above assumes that the parent of `.open-it` contains the data. It's hard to tell without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

try using data attribute. Try looking here:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/

basicly what you will do is giving your data into data atribute and then take it using

var yourContent = $('#link').data('content');